# Android Google Maps not working on published android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I recently published an android app that uses Google Maps V2. The google maps portion of it works fine when debugging. I then went through the process of signing the release certificate and generating the (release) .apk. When the app was published to google play, the google maps part did not work.

The account I used to publish the app is different than the one that has the google maps api enabled. Will changing the account that has the api enabled work, or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: this is happening because, you have to put you SHA1 key along with your package in allowed devices in google api console

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the Google Maps Api Key in AppNameFolder\app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml?

Comment: I haven't changed it since debugging. It worked then.

Comment: You should have a debug and a release folder with the same xml, check that they are the same because once you sign application to upload to Play Store it will use the key in the release folder

Comment: The api key in the release folder was indeed empty, I tried copying the key in the debug folder over to the release one, but after republishing it still didn't work. The google maps screen shows, but its blank.

Answer (score 0):

You must generate a new `Google API key` with your **release** keystore.

Your current Google API key is generated with debug keystore, this is why your map works only on debug.